# In Paris, can one purchase pre-paid sim card upon arrival at CDG airport?

Tags: france, cellphones, paris, cdg

Going to Paris with just 3 days stay. Would like local SIM card, no data. Is it possible to purchase at airport?

Comment: What is not the less important aspect, is it possible to activate the card immediately on the airport?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it wasn't, though you might end up paying a premium

Answer (score 2):

You can only buy Orange SIM card from an Orange store I think, and I've never seen one at CDG. All their stores are listed here: http://agence.orange.fr/. a new SIM card cost just under 10 euros and includes 5 euros of credit.

Comment: It's still called "Mobicarte" I guess. Expect very pricey communications for phoning abroad (from France) with this card. Also there may have a few days of delay for activating phone calls outside France (not sure though, but from personal experience it took 5 days of activation to be able to phone FROM abroad - Netherlands - to France with a Mobicarte)