# SIM card on arrival in Europe (Paris)

Tags: europe, cellphones, paris, switzerland

I'll be travelling from India to Europe (starting with Paris)

Can I get a SIM card from the Paris airport? If yes, what are the documents required? Is just the passport/visa copy enough?
Which is the best operator...I plan to use it for just 7 days in France/Switzerland/Italy/Austria.
Is the SIM card micro-size or i can request it based on my phone?
Also what are the approx charges (incoming/outgoing) ..voice/data ?

Comment: There are many operators, it will be difficult to address all that. Maybe you could edit the question to focus on the “what documents are needed” question (which is well-defined and has not been answered before to my knowledge) and look elsewhere on this site for information on SIM cards, prices in Europe and the like?

Comment: Those are many different questions.

Comment: look at these questions : http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/in-paris-can-one-purchase-pre-paid-sim-card-upon-arrival-at-cdg-airport http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/prepaid-sim-card-for-austria-with-mobile-internet-and-relatively-cheap-foreign http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18570/prepaid-data-plan-for-cell-phone-in-italy it answers most of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to buy a prepaid SIM card at any telecom store in France (You'll run into Orange shops all over Paris, although I'm not sure whether you can find one at the airport). They also sell them in many supermarket (bigger ones, like the Carrefour will certainly have them). The information I have, though first-hand, is a bit dated (2+ years), but I've never been asked for an ID.

I mainly use the cards for local calls and I'd say you can call at least 30 local minutes on a card charged with €10.-. However, most operators charge up to €10.- for the card itself, which is non-refundable.